# Проблема с русскими буквами в Push-уведомлениях

Tags: python, json

Пишу сервис на языке python, который по форме из браузера отправляет push-уведомления Android устройствам. Получилась такая функция:

```
import requests

def send(message, ids):
    url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send'
    headers = {'authorization': 'key=MY_API_KEY', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
    js = '{"notification": {"title": "Test title","text": "' + message + '"},"registration_ids": "' + ','.join(ids) + '"}'
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=js)
    return response
```

Если в переменной **message** русские буквы, от gcm приходит ответ:

```
JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 213.
```

При вводе русских букв все работает отлично.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Какая версия python?

Comment: Не генерируйте json, используя строковое форматирование, используйте `json.dumps()` вместо этого. Также проверьте, что весь текст представлен, используя Юникодные строки (`unicode` тип на Питоне 2 и `str` тип на Питоне 3)

Comment: @IvlevDenis версия python'а 2.7.

Comment: @jfs спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как подсказал @jfs, для создания запроса к GCM необходимо использовать `json.dumps()`:

```
import json

message = u'\u043c\u0438\u0440' # russian letters as Unicode string
ids = [123, 45]
js = json.dumps({
    "notification": {
        "title": "Test title",
        "text": message
    },
    "registration_ids": ids
})
```